# Асинхронность JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код, который возвращает всегда True

```
function IsBlockedUser(idUser, idFriend){
    redis_cli.sismember("user.friend_tmp:" + idUser, idFriend, function(err, friends){
            if(friends == 0) return true;
    });

    return false
}
```

Мало знаком с асинхронностью в js, как я понял, нужен callback для IsBlockedUser

**Edit 2:**

```
user.on("addToList", function(data, cb) {
        SetUserInfoAdd(data, 1, function(data) { // По принципу, который вы указали
            cb(data);
        });

    });
```

Как тут вернуть **cb(data);** для **user.on** ?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, что за функция SetUserInfoAdd?

Comment: Пользовательская - добавляет data в redis

Comment: function SetUserInfoAdd(data, type, cb){ //...// cb(data); }

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, тогда и ответ будет аналогичный - никак не вернуть.   
В интернетах пишут, что sleep не реализовать, и в процессе бесконечного цикла коллбек работать не будет. Сам коллбек должен разбираться, что ему дальше выполнять.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk ещё раз - что за user ? откуда он выдумает параметр cb ?

Comment: Это от socket.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function IsBlockedUser(idUser, idFriend, callback){
    redis_cli.sismember("user.friend_tmp:" + idUser, idFriend, function(err, friends){
            if(friends == 0) return callback(true);
            callback(false);
    });
}

IsBlockedUser(10, 20, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. В дополнение хочу спросить, как быть в таком случае (отредактировал код)